# Tensorflow 2.0.0 install failed on raspberry pi4

Tags: tensorflow, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am attempting to install tensorflow 2.0.0 on my raspberrypi4

```
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.0.0/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

```
pip3 install tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

but it keep saying

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

python version is 3.7.6

how can i fix it?

it actually worked before when i tried it the first time, but i recognized the python version keep changing into 3.9.x everytime i open new terminal (at that time i used pyenv to change python version and installed tensorflow), so i set default python version with another way and it changed to 3.7.6 then i tried to install tensorflow it keep showing that message,

when i try to check the version, maybe it's already installed since i succeeded the first time,
`python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)'`
the result says "No module named 'tensorflow'"

Comment: Could you try to upgrade your version of pip?  `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: It still shows exactly the same error message...